# EC2 Viability Self Test?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Every 1 in 20 or so c4.xlarge EC2 instances I start seems to be a dud. I'm doing live video transcoding so CPU and Network throughput are very important. On a bad instance I can do as low as 5 FPS, while on good instances I can do 30+ FPS with CPU to spare.

Does anyone have any tips for running a viability self-check on boot that will make sure the instance has a good CPU and good network connection before putting it into rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious thing is to throw a small transcoding job at the instance and see how it performs. You can set a low bound on performance and if the instance doesn't match up, kill it and redeploy.

As an aside, have you considered using their Elastic Transcoding service?